Create nvblox depth image from sensor message pointcloud2
I have a rosbag2 with sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2 messages.
I am using Nvblox.
First I would like to ask if there is any way to create a depth image from the point cloud data.
Second I would like to ask if i can retrieve the intrinsic model of a lidar from the point cloud data.
Here is an example of a pointcloud2 message i have.
is_dense: true
---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1721721318
    nanosec: 820235295
  frame_id: os_sensor
height: 32
width: 1024
fields:
- name: x
  offset: 0
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: y
  offset: 4
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: z
  offset: 8
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: intensity
  offset: 16
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: t
  offset: 20
  datatype: 6
  count: 1
- name: reflectivity
  offset: 24
  datatype: 4
  count: 1
- name: ring
  offset: 26
  datatype: 4
  count: 1
- name: ambient
  offset: 28
  datatype: 4
  count: 1
- name: range
  offset: 32
  datatype: 6
  count: 1
is_bigendian: false
point_step: 48
row_step: 49152
data:
- 39
- 182
- 108
- 192
- 163
- 31
- 50
- 187
- 250
- 121
- 182
- 63
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 63
- 0
- 0
- 24
- 66
- 164
- 122
- 239
- 5
- 9
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 43
- 4
- 0
- 0
- 112
- 15
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 160
- 150
- 108
- 192
- 239
- 143
- 163
- 60
- 216
- 98
- 182
- 63
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 63
- 0
- 0
- 224
- 65
- 110
- 9
- 241
- 5
- 6
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 75
- 4
- 0
- 0
- 110
- 15
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 23
- 60
- 109
- 192
- 125
- 45
- 47
- 61
- 19
- 226
- 182
- 63
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 63
- 0
- 0
- 44
- 66
- 142
- 146
- 242
- 5
- 10
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 18
- 4
- 0
- 0

